# it there a way to create a reservation sheet with google with properties dates and checkboxes?

Tags: google-sheets

so  have been trying to create a reservation sheet with dates and the properties and checkboxes,and when for example  make a reservation for 25/5 i would like the checkbox on that date and property to highligh

I have been looking all over google and can t find something similar